# Как убрать дубликаты, и присвоить исходящие тем-же операторам

Tags: postgresql

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
Надо получить количество звонков по каждому оператору, сейчас получилось за двоение операторов из-за исходящих звонков. На входящие используются B2IDUser для исхода используется AIDUser. 
    select  coalesce("B2IDUser","AIDUser") as "Операторы",
    count("ID") filter (where "SeanceType"=1 ) as "Входящие",
    count("ID") filter (where "SeanceType"=2 ) as "Исходящие",
    count("ID") filter (where "SeanceResult"=191) as "Потеранные",
    count("ID") filter (where "SeanceResult"in (192,101,102,191,151) ) as "Всего"from "S_Seances"
    where ("B2IDUser" in(5667834207,5511332770,5667834203,5022050645,5022050649,5022050661,5022050691,5026073792,5030972556,5041139142,5154248810,5022050687,5022050657,5030698089,6051167175,5578934994,5667834199,6071889612,5698847426,5022050675,5026918771,
    5027841073,5148236948,5022050669,5613031592) or "AIDUser" in(5667834207,5511332770,5667834203,5022050645,5022050649,5022050661,5022050691,5026073792,5030972556,5041139142,5154248810,5022050687,5022050657,5030698089,6051167175,5578934994,5667834199,6071889612,5698847426,5022050675,5026918771,
    5027841073,5148236948,5022050669,5613031592)  )
     and "TimeStart">=current_date
    group by "B2IDUser","AIDUser"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Хотелось бы больше данных, потому как, не зная контекст, нельзя быть уверенным в том, что строить решение на базе вашего кода - верно.

Скорее всего, ваша ошибка в том, что вы группируете по двум исходным полям, тогда как следует группировать по одному результирующему столбцу.
Выглядеть это может вот так:

```sql
select
    coalesce(s.B2IDUser, s.AIDUser) as "Операторы",
    count(s.ID) filter (where s.SeanceType = 1 ) as "Входящие",
    count(s.ID) filter (where s.SeanceType = 2 ) as "Исходящие",
    count(s.ID) filter (where s.SeanceResult = 191) as "Потерянные",
    count(s.ID) filter (where s.SeanceResult in (192, 101, 102, 191, 151)) as "Всего"
from S_Seances s
where
    (
        s.B2IDUser in (
            5667834207, 5511332770, 5667834203, 5022050645, 5022050649,
            5022050661, 5022050691, 5026073792, 5030972556, 5041139142,
            5154248810, 5022050687, 5022050657, 5030698089, 6051167175,
            5578934994, 5667834199, 6071889612, 5698847426, 5022050675,
            5026918771, 5027841073, 5148236948, 5022050669, 5613031592
        ) or
        s.AIDUser in (
            5667834207, 5511332770, 5667834203, 5022050645, 5022050649,
            5022050661, 5022050691, 5026073792, 5030972556, 5041139142,
            5154248810, 5022050687, 5022050657, 5030698089, 6051167175,
            5578934994, 5667834199, 6071889612, 5698847426, 5022050675,
            5026918771, 5027841073, 5148236948, 5022050669, 5613031592
        )
    ) and
    s.TimeStart >= current_date
group by 1
```

Comment: @ x-foby Тоже самое, выдал.

Comment: @Playstationgamechannel всё дело в описании вопроса. Старайтесь чуть конкретней описывать, что именно вы хотите получить. Я исправил код, попробуйте сейчас.

Comment: То что надо, спасибо огромное.